# How can I turn off "scrolling the history" in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I have installed the new iTerm 2.
It asked me in a yellow bar at the top if I'd like to enable a mouse feature. Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact sentence anymore.

By accident I approved. Now when I use the scroll wheel on the mouse in iTerm, it doesn't scroll the up anymore, but instead it goes triggers the command history as if I had pressed the up-cursor.

Where I can toggle this option to turn it off again?

Comment: I assume that you use iTerm2.9, and the message you saw is "Do you want the scroll wheel to move the cursor in interactive programs like this?".However i can't find a interface to toggle it, do you still have the problem?

Comment: Yes but only when I'm logged into a server via ssh. I don't know how this could be connected.

Comment: "only when I'm logged into a server via ssh", you mean that when you use iTerm2 for local operations, that will not happen? Do you use a different 'profile' when 'logged into a server via ssh' ?

Comment: There must be a terminal control character sent to turn Alternate Screen on and off. I'm thinking it's better long term (not specific to iTerm2 or vim or less) to learn what that control character is. It could be `ESC [ ? 1 0 4 9 l` or `ESC [ ? 1 0 4 7 l` or `ESC [ ? 47 l` (https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html)

Comment: this just started happening randomly for me.. frustrating when you're trying to look through logs

Comment: It's a mode (alternate screen) for terminal emulation set by the remote to your terminal which is then left on and not set back if you exit the program setting it (like less, vim, or others) unexpectedly (eg disconnect ssh). The command `reset` will assert to set the initial conditions for your terminal again. I know it has a scary name, feel free to read the man page first. Likewise `tput rmcup` sets it off IF you're sure it's on. There's probably a way to ask for the state to be shown, but terminals get complicated.

Answer (score 778, accepted):

A few terminals, including iTerm2, have a feature where they change the behavior of the wheel mouse when a full-screen program such as `vi`, or `screen` or `tmux` is running.  This happens when those programs use the *alternate screen*, to provide a useful function.  Normally, when using the alternate screen in iTerm2, the wheel mouse acts like the scrollbar, scrolling the entire screen up/down.  But when this feature is enabled, iTerm2 sends cursor up/down keys, making your command-history change.

As suggested in another comment, select the *Preferences* menu:

[image]

and in that, select the *Advanced* tab.  Scroll down to the **Mouse** section,

[image]

and toggle the entry for

*Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode*

from **Yes** to **No**.  You will have to restart iTerm2 for the change to take effect.  (With iTerm2 *v3.1.5* changes take effect without restarting.)

Comment: I tested it before writing the comment - just toggling the option was not enough.

Comment: Might depend on the version. In 3.0.2, toggling is definitely sufficient. In fact, if you are in alternate screen mode and this setting is off and you try (and fail) to scroll with the mouse and subsequently press the up or down arrow key, you'll be prompted to turn this feature on right in the terminal window.

Comment: 3.0.12 does not need to be restarted for this to take effect.

Comment: // , I like this feature, and use it in Vim. How do I _exit_ alternate screen mode in a given terminal window? UPDATE: In the terminal that is in alternate screen mode, open a terminal program that activates the alternate screen mode. Exit that program cleanly. This temporarily ends the problem. I think this indicates that the problem was caused by exiting a program that used the Alternate Screen feature in an unusual way.

Comment: Sir, you saved me from pure insanity.

Comment: This is the preference for the correct and expected behavior WHEN IN THE ALTERNATE SCREEN. Instead of disabling it, you need instead to exit the alternate screen.

Comment: @NathanBasanese said: "open a terminal program that activates the alternate screen mode."  for those who don't know which programs do this, *vi* is a program that does this for me (and it is most likely installed in most machines).

Comment: This is a very aggravating behavior to be enabled by default. freaked me out

Comment: This must be the worst single feature ever implemented in any software on any planet.

Comment: One of those ideas that sounds great on paper but no one actually wants in practice. But they have to make it default otherwise it will never get used and they will never find out how much users don't want it.

Comment: Sometimes the switch from scrollbar to up/down keys happens arbitrarily.

Comment: This is useful in vim, but the fact that it hijacks scrolling when not in an alternate screen like the shell prompt makes it entirely too aggravating. Also, when you disable it, iTerm will immediately ask you to turn it back on when you scroll, so after disabling it you will have to also click “don’t ask again"

Comment: Ah thank you, happened to me when accessing a `screen` session. Very annoying indeed.

Comment: Just adding that in 3.4.19, `Preferences` wasn't there. It's `Settings...`

Comment: Thank you ... this was driving me bananas.

Answer (score 117):

If you are trapped in the scrolling history mode, you can escape by **running vi and exiting.** You can also choose another program that uses the alternate screen and then exit.

Scrolling the history with the mouse wheel should in theory never happen. It happens in practice because sometimes the alternate screen mode is not correctly switched back. The accepted answer solves the problem by deactivating a feature that is useful, namely scrolling in vi, less, ... with the mouse wheel or trackpad. You can keep the option from the advanced preferences:

> Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode

set to yes. You will sometimes be trapped in the scroll history mode. But if you know how to escape, it's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! This helped me out :)

Comment: Thanks man! But entering and exiting vi didn't help in my case for some reason, but it worked after entering a man page and exiting it by pressing q

Comment: This was so helpful. Scrolling was all of a sudden adding `[[A^` and `[[B^` to the command line instead of scrolling the window. I knew this was not normal behavior. Prior to that I had left the computer in `nano` in an SSH shell that got disconnected when I shut my laptop. That abrupt exit was obviously the culprit. Simply opening a new tab in iTerm2 fixed this.

Comment: Unfortunately when using `screen` you cannot use this trick to exit alternate screen mode. So if you are using `screen` a lot (like me), disabling the feature altogether is a life saver.

Comment: I prefer this answer, because it is very useful to navigate in fullscreen apps with the trackpad, so disabling the feature in preferences was not a good option for me :) Thx for sharing this tip :)

Answer (score 67):

You probably just need to get out of alternate console.

Try: `tput rmcup`

Comment: Great answer A+ 

Comment: Much better answer - this lets you scroll the history while still being able to scroll while in vim. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone add an explanation to this answer, what are tput and rmcup? I mean specifics, obviously the end result is that it stops the alternate console mode.

Comment: Another option is to run `reset`; that worked for me and is slightly easier to remember than `tput rmcup`

Answer (score 24):

With iTerm2 you can also hold Option while using the scroll wheel to force window scrolling, in case you do want the wheel to continue to work in vim.

Comment: this works, but how do I go back to the detaults, when I did not have to hold the option key

Answer (score 22):

Preferences:Advanced:Mouse:Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate mode

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue described, but in the newest iTerm Mouse is not under the Prefences:Advanced. Just triggers, smart selection, and semantic history. Anyone know any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The behavior you're seeing is the expected (and correct) behavior when in the alternate screen. The only problem you have is that you dropped into bash, or whatever, on the alternate screen, possibly while losing a connection or from a killed vim or less. EG you were in `less +F /var/log/something` and got disconnected.

You see someone has already written that the `tput rmcup` command will exit to the main screen.

I also went ahead and looked up some terminal control characters. It can be any of: `ESC [ ? 1 0 4 9 l` or `ESC [ ? 1 0 4 7 l` or `ESC [ ? 47 l` (gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html) with a preference to the first.

I'm generally successful in iTerm2 with `echo -e '\e[?1049l'` I actually don't find `rmcup` any easier to remember, restore memory of console up?.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a more recent version of MacOS (mine is Monterey 12.0.1) and don't see the "Mouse" option under preferences, you can find this option by going to "Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard tab" and then uncheck the box "Scroll alternate screen" as shown in the red box below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and none of the solutions I read and tried worked. What fixed my problem was turning Secure Keyboard Entry off and now when I use the mouse to scroll it in ssh and in terminal mode on macOS 10.13 it works like I expect it too!

Answer (score 0):

as of 2023 `CMD + R` gets you out of the `Alternate mode`

Answer (score -1):

##### An update in 2022

In Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal
[image]

uncheck the

- "Save lines to scrollback in alternate screen mode" and
- "Save lines to scrollback when an app status bar is present"