# How to exit alternate screen scrolling on iTerm2 Vim?

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim, iterm2, iterm

First, sorry if the title isn't precise. I'm in a weird situation, while using Vim on Mac iTerm2. More precisely, when I release two finger click it scrolls down 3 lines.

Sort of same thing is mentioned at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=683942 and its referred as "alternate screen scrolling".

How do I came in this situation? Well, I was in a remote ssh session and just just closed macbook, put it on bag and went to lunch. When I came back I experienced this strange thing.

It seems the same issue is mentioned at [How can I turn off "scrolling the history" in iTerm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594420/how-can-i-turn-off-scrolling-the-history-in-iterm2).

It only happens on iTerm2, not on Terminal.

So how do I go out of alternate screen?

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
tput rmcup
```

(which assumes that vim used the terminal description to switch to the alternate screen), or

```
printf '\033[?1049l'
```

which makes fewer assumptions.

Further reading: [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)

Comment: I tried both. Still when I release two finger click it scrolls down 3 lines. Any suggestion? Am I correct if I think this is an iTerm issue or perhaps something happened outside iTerm? I bet it was related to iTerm and re-installed it but even so, the same thing. Perhaps there is an even more inelegant solution.